# Parachute material used for the Venera probes to survive 500 °C

Tags: venus, lander, soviet-union, venera

The Venera landers of the former Soviet Union were quite successful on the very hot surface of Venus.

Which material was used for the parachutes to survive 500 °C?

What about cotton wool? Yes this fiber will burn in air at 500 °C but there is no free oxygen in the atmosphere of Venus.

There is a process for the production of carbon fibers by heating of rayon fibers without oxygen. "Rayon is a synthetic fiber, made from natural sources of regenerated cellulose, such as wood and related agricultural products." Of cause cotton wool is cellulose too.

Thomas Alva Edison held a patent describing several ways of creating the carbon filament including "cotton and linen thread, wood splints, papers coiled in various ways". Carbon filaments used for electric light

See Wikipedia for
[Carbon Fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_fibers), [Kohlenstofffaser](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohlenstofffaser#Rayon/Viskose_(Cellulose)) and
[Rayon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayon).

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Venera-spacecraft-What-materials-were-used-for-the-parachutes-to-allow-them-to-withstand-the-atmosphere-of-Venus

Comment: The parachute of Venera 7 failed (though the probe did still complete a soft landing), so presumably there was an iterative process in material choice.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys From Wikipedia about Venera 7 : "The parachute was initially reefed down to 1.8 square meters, opening to 2.5 square meters 13 minutes later, when the reefing line melted as designed.[5] Six minutes after the unreefing, the parachute started to fail, resulting in a descent more rapid than planned." What a clever unreefing using a melting line. Unreefing with an explosive charge as used for Apollo is not possible on Venus.

Comment: @Uwe interesting point! I've just asked [Premature detonation of explosive bolts when landing on hot Venus?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53690/12102) and in Chemistry SE  [Constraints on pyrotechnic explosives that won't detonate spontaneously at 500 C when landing on Venus?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/152868/16035)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

technically it was fiberglass with acrylic fibers - "стеклонитрон"("glass-nitron").

> It was necessary to get down through the hot atmosphere quickly, but not hit the surface too hard. To accomplish this, the main parachute was reefed, a cord wrapped around the parachute cables held the mouth of the chute closed like a goblet, and the capsule descended rapidly. At a temperature of 200° C, the reefing cord was designed to melt, allowing the chute to open fully for a soft landing. Of course the parachute itself had to withstand over 500° C, and it was made of a heat resistant fiber of unknown composition ("glass nitron"). To further prolong mission time, the capsule was precooled to -8° C before separation from the main spacecraft.

http://mentallandscape.com/V_Lavochkin1.htm

[Roscosmos: 50th anniversary of the launch of the automatic interplanetary station "Venera-7"](https://www.roscosmos.ru/29042/)

> Высокое атмосферное давление позволило заменить двухкаскадную парашютную систему на однокаскадную с рифленым парашютом конусной
> формы площадью 2,8 м² — это чуть больше, чем площадь купола тормозного
> парашюта на «Венере-4». Изготовлен парашют был из отечественного
> материала стеклонитрон. Для обеспечения достаточной прочности купол
> парашюта изготавливался из 4 слоев ткани. После выгорания нитрона
> обеспечивалась воздухопроницаемость купола, гарантирующая его надежное
> функционирование. Соответственно была изменена и автоматика ввода
> парашютной системы.
>
> The high atmospheric pressure made it possible to replace the
> two-stage parachute system with a single-stage one with a corrugated
> parachute of a conical shape with an area of ​​2.8 m², which is
> slightly more than the area of ​​the braking parachute canopy on
> Venera-4. The parachute was made from the domestic material
> **"glassonitron"**. To ensure sufficient strength, the parachute canopy was
> made of 4 layers of fabric. **After the nitron burned out, air
> permeability of the dome was ensured, guaranteeing its reliable
> operation**. Accordingly, the automation of the parachute system was
> changed.

Comment: Acrylic fibers would melt below 200 °C; did the parachute fabric contain acrylic fibers, or does acrylic fibers refer to the reefed cord that melts?

Comment: @uhoh After the parachute is opened, these acrylic fibers are no longer needed. They give "softness" to the fabrics of packed parachute. When theacrylic fibers melts, parashute turns into a hard fiberglass dome. We're not going to use this parachute again, are we? :)

Comment: *How cool!* Why not mention that in the answer? Or shall I ask it as a separate question?

Comment: @uhoh I'll just add a quote - I remembered how this material is called in Russian.